# Formal proof of ($A$ and ($A$ implies $B$)) implies $B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

> $$(A ∧ (A → B)) ⇒ B$$

I know that this is a tautology, but apart from setting up a truth-table I dont know how I would go about a formal proof in discrete mathematics. thanks

[image]

Comment: start from $A\to B=\lnot A\lor B$ then distribute $\land$ over $\lor$ and simplify.

Comment: It seems notations differ by location. What is the difference between $\rightarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: It depends on what "environment" for formal proof you are using...

Comment: It's just one of the essential, self-evident and defining properties of logical implication. It shouldn't need a proof. Yes, I'm sure you can concoct a list of less self-evident axioms and derive this principle (Detachment or Modus Ponens) from those axioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semantic reasoning ( not sure it counts as a " formal" proof)

Suppose the antecedent does not imply logically the consequent.

It means there is ( at least) one interpretation inwhich the antecedent is true and the consequent false.

Hence, an interpretation in which $B$ is false and $( (A\land (A\rightarrow B))$ is true ( meaning is particular that $A$ is true).

The only way to have $(A\rightarrow B)$ true is not to have both  $A$ true and $B$ false.

But the only way to have this when you alredy have $B$ false is not to have $A$ true, hence to have  $A$ false.

By what precedes,however,  you have $A$ true.

This shows that there is no possible  interpretation that falsifies the original material conditional, and, consequently, that the antecedent logically implies the consequent.

Answer (score 2):

$(A \land (A\rightarrow B)) \rightarrow B $ is true when $A \land (A\rightarrow B)$ is false or $B$ is true. Therefore if it was false then $A \land (A\rightarrow B)$ would be true and $B$ would be false.

If $A \land (A\rightarrow B)$ is false then A is false and $A\rightarrow B$ is false.
But if $A\rightarrow B$ is false and $B$ is false then $A$ must be true, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I think your last line should say $A$ is true. This was more or less the exact same argument I had in mind. Great work.

Comment: you are right, thank you! :)

Comment: Second paragraph, first sentence. If a conjunction is false, then it is EITHER the first OR second conjunct is false. Not AND.

Answer (score 1):

To go from another direction, you can construct a proof using the deduction theorem to transform the problem first into $\{A \wedge (A \to B)\} \vdash B$. Then this is proved by the following:

1. $A \wedge (A \to B)$ (hypothesis).
2. $A$ ($\wedge$-elimination on 1).
3. $A \to B$ ($\wedge$-elimination on 1).
4. $B$ (modus ponens on 2 and 3).

Comment: Please could you comment on your solution and explain in which sense there is no "circle in proving". The reason that makes it apparently circular is that modus ponens is used to prove modus ponens. Does the false appearence lie in a syntax/ semantics confusion or an object language / metalanguage one?

Comment: Modus ponens is a rule of the metalanguage, but it's not automatically true of the *theory*. I've assumed we're working in a logic which includes modus ponens. Per https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376048/are-there-logics-without-modus-ponens, of course, there are logics which don't allow modus ponens, but I'm not aware of a logic without modus ponens in which you can prove something by two-valued truth table.

Comment: To be precise, in the introductory course in propositional logic I took many years ago, a *proof* was defined as an ordered list of sentences, each either an axiom, a hypothesis, or a line of the form $q$ where an earlier line was of the form $p \to q$ and another earlier line was of the form $p$. In that setting, modus ponens was assumed as part of the background logic (it was the name given to that third rule), but it had no direct translation into symbols in a formal proof.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.